# Decoding Gmail login

Tags: gmail

I just noticed some a suspicious login into my Gmail account. When I check my login history, I see one entry that looks like:

> Access Type:
>   Browser (Chrome)
>
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)"
>
> (Browser, mobile, POP3, etc.) Location (IP address)   United States (CO) (2601:283:c200:8782:8039:dc84:e32c:513a)

It appears to be a Windows 7 login, which I do not own. The IP address given is foreign to me and I don't know how to decode it. Does anyone know?

I would like to change my password, but I think it is someone stalking me (someone I am in legal issues with currently, so I want to find out if it is actually that person).

Comment: What's preventing you from changing your password? What would knowing the IP address provide you?

Comment: You could also try contacting Gmail support.

Comment: Are you certain that is not your own IP address?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing encoded in the log example, it's just a regular IPv6 address. According to [db-ip](https://db-ip.com/2601%3A283%3Ac200%3A8782%3A8039%3Adc84%3Ae32c%3A513a).

> 2601:283:c200:8782:8039:dc84:e32c:513a is an IPv6 address owned by Comcast Cable Communications and located in Pueblo, United States

If you are in a legal dispute and suspect being a victim of stalking, you should cooperate with your local authorities.

Comment: Thank you. I contacted my local police and my attorney. This is extremely weird. I changed my password, and this person logged in again after I changed my password. If this person is the person I am in legal disputes with, who is not tech savvy at all, so I don't understand how they could have possibly logged in again afterwards.

Comment: I am actually using a university email that uses the gmail.com domain. My university does not currently allow two-step verification. Is there any way to check what this person may have been doing to my account? I suspect they are reading my emails to my attorney.

Comment: @David If it is a University account, then the University admins have access to your account. For legal matters, I'd highly suggest getting your own personal account.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with university/gmail accounts - but how would the university admins have access? I'd say that would be a grave misconfiguration. I'd rather say, as it is a semi-public computer (?), that a keylogger or the like may be the tool to get access. How else has access to the device you used to change your password?

Comment: @SaAtomic If it's a Google powered email system, it'll provide functions like any other commercial email system to the domain administrators - they can gain access to accounts, control what login functions to allow, and otherwise monitor mails to and from the accounts. This would normally use the Gmail interface, but a different domain name - see https://www.google.com/edu/products/productivity-tools/

Comment: @Matthew wow. that seems like a security/privacy nightmare..

Comment: @SaAtomic Not really - they're essentially corporate accounts. This is the same functionality that an Exchange administrator has in a Windows domain. I doubt that such access would leave traces as shown though - read my answer to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149511/is-there-any-authentication-system-whose-protocol-always-notifies-the-target-ac/150092#150092 for some reasons why